# Rails/Angular CSRF Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ruby, csrf, x-xsrf-token

I have a Rails API backend with Angular frontend. Of course, it was all good while playing in development.

The app is deployed using nginx+passenger, with the compiled angular content (`dist` dir) is simply put in the Rails `public` dir. I repeatedly get 422 error, as the rails server `Can't verify CSRF token`.

I have installed the [angular_rails_csrf](https://github.com/jsanders/angular_rails_csrf) gem, also added the following line to `application.rb`:

```
config.angular_rails_csrf_cookie_name = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'
```

but it still doesn't work. Obviously it works just fine when setting `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in the app controller but that's just stupid.

I have tried various solutions, none of them helped. Anybody got an idea how to overcome this?

---

System info:

- Ruby version 2.6.5
- Rails version 6.0.2.1
- Angular version 9.1.0

Comment: Have you configured nginx to forward the https headers to passenger?

Comment: (1) dunno, I've followed the tutorial on passenger's website
(2) it's on http